# Powershell Command for downloading .Net Core 5.0.4 Hosting Bundle Installer

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-8, powershell-4.0

It is really frustrating to ask this question. I am trying to download "runtime-aspnetcore-5.0.4-windows-hosting-bundle-installer". For that, I am using these straightforward PowerShell commands -

```
 $temp_path = "C:\temp1"
 $wh_installer_url = "https://dotnet.microsoft.com/permalink/dotnetcore-current-windows-runtime-bundle-installer"
 $wh_installer_file = $temp_path + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName( $wh_installer_url )
 Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $wh_installer_url -OutFile $wh_installer_file
```

The main issue is "$wh_installer_url". I could not find out the correct link to download the file. I looked at "https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0". There seems to be a link for hosting bundle. But while inspecting it, I found that it was pointing to "thank you " page.  Then I looked at Microsoft doc and found out this link. Apparently, it also downloaded a page, which is not an installer, but most likely a "thank you" page.
I need a PowerShell command or a bunch of them to download .Net Core 5.0.4 Hosting Bundle Installer.

Comment: On the thank you page there is a box with the "direct link" in it (https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/2281cc70-3851-4dec-b418-4f5be60d8f2e/0163e524e63c2bb07d9da642ca1468d5/dotnet-hosting-5.0.4-win.exe)

You could use that as $wh_installer_url.

Answer (score 2):

The official way is,

1. Use [the full index JSON](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/releases-index.json) to determine the major releases you might need.
2. Use the release specific JSON to learn the actual patch release you should check and the relevant download links, like [this .NET 5 specific file](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/release-metadata/5.0/releases.json).